# How to access Json type returned from server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Guys I have this response from server:

```
{"copy_am_email":"0","locations": [array here ... .....]}
```

which im pretty sure is a json type (I console logged it). That data above is fetched by ajax:

```
success    : function ( data ) {
   alert (data.locations[index]); //I should be able to access locations even without index
}
```

But my problem is `locations` is undefined. Or even `copy_am_email`. I accessed it like this:

```
data.locations . I even tried this data['locations'].
```

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is parsed into an object?

Comment: What method are you using to fetch the data? It's only parsed into an object if you are using a method specific for JSON, or if the response has the correct content type so that jQuery (or if you use something else?) can guess that it's JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u have to parse it:

```
newJSON = JSON.parse( myJson );
```

i should note that you have the number zero as a string `"0"` it should just be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the JSON data using javascript's native method JSON.parse(data). Then try accessing locations the way you do.